# How to indent the first line of a multiline paragraph using jspdf

Tags: indentation, jspdf, multiline

I need to print a multiline paragraph with the first line indented using jsPDF.

I splitted my text with .splitTextToSize function using option textIndent.
Then used .text to render the result. See code below :

```
doc = mbjsPDF({
    orientation: 'portrait',    
    unit: 'mm', 
    format: 'a4' 
});

var text = "To be, or not to be, that is the question: Whether 'tis nobler in the mind to suffer The slings and arrows of outrageous fortune";

var textTab = doc.splitTextToSize(text, 100, {textIndent: 30});
doc.text(10, 20, textTab);

doc.save('test.pdf');
```

Actual result:

```
To be, or not to be, that is
the question: Whether 'tis nobler in the
mind to suffer The slings and arrows of
outrageous fortune
```

Expected result: (I want the first line shifted by 30mm)

```
            To be, or not to be, that is
the question: Whether 'tis nobler in the
mind to suffer The slings and arrows of
outrageous fortune
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about `option textIndent`, but if you have only one paragraph, you may simply add a tab to the beginning of that paragraph.

`var textTab = doc.splitTextToSize('    ' + text, 100);`

> I [mainly use jsPDF](https://medium.com/@weihui.guo/which-javascript-library-should-i-use-for-client-side-html-to-pdf-conversion-77f25e40f782?source=friends_link&sk=1e643f9308eebdb36f68758cf34a33d1) to convert HTML to PDF. If you just want to convert plain text, maybe you can consider [pdfmake](https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/getting-started/client-side/methods/) as well. It has an auto page break and is easy to add the margin, etc.

```
<script src="http://pdfmake.org/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://pdfmake.org/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script>
    function print() {
        // open the PDF in a new window
        pdfMake.createPdf(dd).open();
    }

    var dd = {
        content: [{
            leadingIndent: 30,
            lineHeight: 1.5, // optional
            text: "To be, or not to be, that is the question: Whether 'tis nobler in the mind to suffer The slings and arrows of outrageous fortune"
        }]
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your advise and for the update of my post (it is much better :-) ). I will considere pdfmake.

Answer (score 0):

textIndent is used for the space between lines, it's really confusing!
You could make the first line a seperate text component. Than you can change the x parameter of the [Text](http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/jsPDF.html#text) class.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I finally used a workaround : instead of calling doc.text on the whole paragraph, I printed first textTab[0] which I aligned on the right then textTab[1] to textTab[n] which I aligned ont he left. It is not ideal but it works.